# How to determine the time taken from bigO notation?

Tags: big-o

For example, for O(N) if n = 5;
Can we say that this function ideally takes 5 miliseconds to execute or something like that? Since it is a notation for timing, I assume it should say more about the time like this.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not how it works. It's a notation for indicating how much the time will tend to grow based on different amounts of data, but not how long specifically an operation will take.

For example, in Java, using a HashMap is probably going to be slower than using a TreeMap for very small collection sizes. There's a certain amount of overhead to set up the data structure, you have to calculate the hashes of each of the items, etc. But since inserting and retrieving items from a HashMap is O(1) (also called "constant time"; it doesn't change depending on the collection size), while inserting and retrieving from a TreeMap is O(ln n) (the time grows as the logarithm of the size of the collection), before the collection gets very large, the HashMap will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the programming language and computer's power. You can't exactly determine the time taken. Because same process (i.e assignment) may take different time on different languages. But you can use timers to measure the time taken by the process.